# Does VHDL allow a std_logic_vector port with no bounds?

Tags: vhdl

Here is a code from VUnit Avalon Master BFM:

```
entity avalon_master is
  generic (
    bus_handle          : bus_master_t;
    use_readdatavalid   : boolean := true;
    fixed_read_latency  : natural := 1;  -- (bus cycles).  This parameter is ignored when use_readdatavalid is true
    write_high_probability : real range 0.0 to 1.0 := 1.0;
    read_high_probability : real range 0.0 to 1.0 := 1.0
  );
  port (
    clk           : in  std_logic;
    address       : out std_logic_vector;
    byteenable    : out std_logic_vector;
    burstcount    : out std_logic_vector;
    waitrequest   : in  std_logic;
    write         : out std_logic;
    writedata     : out std_logic_vector;
    read          : out std_logic;
    readdata      : in  std_logic_vector;
    readdatavalid : in  std_logic
  );
end entity;
```

There are so many ports that just say std_logic_vector without giving any bounds. This is obviously only for use in simulation actually. How is this even valid VHDL?

Comment: Which version of VHDL? 2008 and newer add capabilities that earlier versions didn't have.

Comment: I am not sure but this could be VHDL 2008. It is code from the VUnit testing framework.

Comment: Yes for all revisions of VHDL.   It is similar to subprograms in this way.   However, your synthesis tools may or may not like this.   So I primarily use it for verification.   Good news with Vivado below, however, I would still be cautious with synthesis code.

Comment: Thanks Jim, this is code for a BFM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This unconstrained declaration is valid, but it depends on another definition outside this module. Note that no *"generic"* declaration is required for this simple D Flip-Flop example:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity uncon_dff is
    Port ( d : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR;
           clk, rst : in STD_LOGIC;
           q : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR);
end uncon_dff;

architecture Behavioral of uncon_dff is
begin
    process (clk, rst)
    begin
        if (rst = '1') then
            q <= (others => '0');
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
            q <= d;
        end if;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

The top level design defines the ranges of the vectors at the instantiation (from the local signals/inputs/outputs):

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity top_dff is
    Port ( d : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
           clk, rst : in STD_LOGIC;
           q : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0));
end top_dff;

architecture Behavioral of top_dff is

    component uncon_dff is -- no range here (unconstrained)
        Port ( d : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR;
               clk, rst : in STD_LOGIC;
               q : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR);
    end component;

begin

    dff : uncon_dff port map ( -- ranges inherited
        d => d, clk => clk, rst => rst, q => q  
    );

end Behavioral;
```

Which generates the expected logic:

[image]

This was tested on Vivado using VHDL 2008. If the top level design mistakenly defines different ranges for 'd' and 'q', the synthesis fails:

> [Synth 8-690] width mismatch in assignment; target has 9 bits, source has 8 bits ["/dev/shm/project_1/project_1.srcs/sources_1/new/uncon_dff.vhd":18]